# Sum digits of each integer in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, integer

I was trying to sum the digits for every element in the list and print the sum of every element at once but my code below only gives me 6 6 6. My desired output is 6 1 2.

```
#pythonCode#

 my_list = [15, 10, 20]

 sum = 0

 m = ""

 for i in range(0, 3):

while m != 0:

    rem= my_list[i] % 10

    m = my_list[i] //10

    my_list[i] = m

    sum = sum + rem

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply a lambda function - if I understand the desired output correctly:

```
>>> my_list = [15, 10, 20]
>>> list(map(lambda x: sum(int(s) for s in str(x)), my_list))
[6, 1, 2]
```

Written out in full, this is roughly equivalent to:

```
my_list = [15, 10, 20]

for integer in my_list:
    total = 0
    for digit in str(integer):
        total += int(digit)
    print(f"The sum of {integer} is {total}")
```

**Output:**

```
The sum of 15 is 6
The sum of 10 is 1
The sum of 20 is 2
```